# Unable to publish service with https endpoint in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to publish the WSO2 Message Broker services using the WSO2 API Manager.

If I enter the Message Broker URL containing https:// in the Publisher and validate the endpoint, it returns 'Invalid'. I can save the API however. Specifying http:// results in a valid endpoint.

Using SoapUI to test the EventBrokerService gives a valid response (status 202) accessing the Message Broker directly. Via the API Manager I get a soap:Fault:

```
<soapenv:Fault>
    <faultcode xmlns:axis2ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">axis2ns6:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Error in Sender</faultstring>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a hostname verification failure. So when you publish an API through API Manager you need to set the **HostnameVerifier** parameter in 
<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.

<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>

Please refer https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/Creating+an+API for more information.

Comment: With the right certificates and this setting it works.

Comment: Nobody in production will use SoapUI, when it comes to production you can specify the hosts.